# Global variable Array

Tags: color, external-files

I have `control_array.tex` and 10 `templateA.tex`, `templateB.tex`, ... TeX files. In `control_array.tex`:

- ArrayName = [Name1,Name2,...Name10]
- ArrayColor =  [Color1,Color2,...Color10]

With Array in `control_array.tex` I can change all variable only one time in all templates: `templateA.tex`, `templateB.tex`, ...

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
%Call Name1, Nam10...Color 1, Color2...Color10
\begin{enumerate}
\item \textcolor{color1}{Name1}
\item \textcolor{color2}{Name2}
\item \textcolor{color3}{Name3}
\end{enumerate}
\textcolor{color4}{Name9} \\
\textcolor{color5}{Name8}
\end{document}
```

How can I do it with LaTeX? Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Constant arrays are easy, variable arrays use things like `\csname name\theindex\endcsname`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `pgffor` for that.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\ArrayNames{{"koala","duck","marmot","penguin","bear"}}
\def\ArrayColors{{"gray","yellow","blue","red","brown"}}
\begin{enumerate}
\foreach \X in {0,...,4}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myname}{\ArrayNames[\X]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\ArrayColors[\X]}
\item \textcolor{\mycolor}{\myname}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with an external file (which I create here for the convenience of others in the MWE, but you may drop the filecontents stuff as long you have a data file).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{myarrays.tex}
\def\ArrayNames{{"koala","duck","marmot","penguin","bear"}}
\def\ArrayColors{{"gray","yellow","blue","red","brown"}}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\input{myarrays.tex}
\begin{enumerate}
\foreach \X in \ArrayNames
{\foreach \Y [count=\Z starting from 0]in \X 
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\ArrayColors[\Z]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myname}{\ArrayNames[\Z]}
\item \textcolor{\mycolor}{\myname}}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

And of course you can install any mapping. Here is an example (in which I assume you already have created `myarrays.tex`, if not uncomment the corresponding lines).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
% \usepackage{filecontents}
% \begin{filecontents*}{myarrays.tex}
% \def\ArrayNames{{"koala","duck","marmot","penguin","bear"}}
% \def\ArrayColors{{"gray","yellow","blue","red","brown"}}
% \end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\input{myarrays.tex}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/declare function={mymap(\x)=int(mod(1+\x*\x,4));}}
\begin{enumerate}
\foreach \X in \ArrayNames
{\foreach \Y [count=\Z starting from 0]in \X 
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\ArrayColors[mymap(\Z)]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myname}{\ArrayNames[\Z]}
\item \textcolor{\mycolor}{\myname}}}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, this function is chosen such that it distinguishes between birds on the one hand and mammals and beings on the other hand.

Comment: thank for your quick reply. I know that pgffor in same file.tex can do it. Can you solution/idea set variable array in control file, not in template file?  \def\ArrayNames{{"koala","duck","marmot","penguin","bear"}}
\def\ArrayColors{{"gray","yellow","blue","red","brown"}} Thanks

Comment: and some situation,  please not use "For each", example: \textcolor{color4}{Name9} \\
    \textcolor{color5}{Name8}. thanks

Comment: @tisaigon I do not understand your last requests. Could you please try to be more specific? Note, however, that I added a proposal that loads an external file.

Comment: thank so much. when i compile your code in overleaf: ok, but compile in texmarker in my computer: "file not found". Can you please write code only for "myarrays.tex" file: \def\ArrayNames{{"koala","duck","marmot","penguin","bear"}}
\def\ArrayColors{{"gray","yellow","blue","red","brown"}}. right? or need begin{document} end{document}? Thanks

Comment: @tisaigon `myarrays.tex` needs only to have `\def\ArrayNames{{"koala","duck","marmot","penguin","bear"}} \def\ArrayColors{{"gray","yellow","blue","red","brown"}}` in it.

Comment: thanks, my last request that in your code can  \textcolor{color4}{Name9};  \textcolor{color5}{Name8} => not always: color4 & name 4, color5 & name 5..

Comment: @tisaigon Yes, but there must be some mapping/some rule according to which a color gets assigned to a name. What is your proposal for this rule?

Comment: Thanks. i don't use rule for this situation. Maybe total element of colour array > total element of name array. And sometimes i need simple call: Name (x) and Colour (y) together. Or only colour (y) for other text not in "name array".

Comment: @tisaigon I added a mapping function (the flexibility of adding this very easily may be an advantage of this approach), which you can adjust to your needs.

Comment: thanks, how i can call one element from this array. Example: penguin in Name Array.

Comment: @tisaigon The penguin is indexed 3 (the index starts at 0) : `\pgfmathsetmacro{\penguinname}{\ArrayNames[3]}`.

Comment: maybe im dumm sorry for what i've done, but i can not call penguin with your code: \pgfmathsetmacro{\penguinname}{\ArrayNames[3]}. My result row is blank/invisible

Comment: @tisaigon What does `\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\input{myarrays.tex}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myname}{\ArrayNames[3]}
\myname
\end{document}` give you?

Comment: Thank you marmot. Done after added "\myname"

Comment: when i use this element in tcolorbox. ex: \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=green!25, title={\pgfmathsetmacro{\myname}{\ArrayNames[3]} \myname}]
    Content
\end{tcolorbox}. Title is ok, but colback is fail. How can i replace "Green!25" with \pgfmathsetmacro{\myname}{\ArrayColors[3]} \myname. Thanks

Comment: @tisaigon Could you please ask a new question for that. I am just about to go to bed and others will help you more quickly. If you are lucky, Christian Hupfer sees your question, then you will get an excellent answer.

Answer (score 4):

Trivial with `listofitems`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listofitems,xcolor}
\newcommand\ArrayNames{Name1,Name2,N3,N4,N5,N6,N7,N8,N9,Name10}
\newcommand\ArrayColors{red,blue,cyan,cyan!50!red,red!50,
  purple,green,yellow,blue!50,magenta}
\readlist*\arrayname{\ArrayNames}
\readlist*\arraycolor{\ArrayColors}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\foreachitem\x\in\arrayname{\item \textcolor{\arraycolor[\xcnt]}{\x}}
\end{enumerate}

\textcolor{\arraycolor[4]}{\arrayname[9]}

\textcolor{\arraycolor[5]}{\arrayname[8]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can have files with the following structure

```
\colorlist{
  {red}
  {green}
  {blue}
  {green!40!yellow}
  {-green!40!yellow}
  {rgb:-green!40!yellow,3;green!40!yellow,2;red,1}
  {red>wheel,12}
}
```

It would also be possible to have the simpler structure

```
red
green
blue
green!40!yellow
```

- green!40!yellow
    rgb:-green!40!yellow,3;green!40!yellow,2;red,1
    red>wheel,12

if preferred. Then in the document you call

```
\assigncolors{<filename>}{<list of names for the colors>}
```

Here's the code, using `filecontents` for making the example self-contained; the name for the color list file can be whatever you prefer.

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.colors}
\colorlist{
  {red}
  {green}
  {blue}
  {green!40!yellow}
  {-green!40!yellow}
  {rgb:-green!40!yellow,3;green!40!yellow,2;red,1}
  {red>wheel,12}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\assigncolors}{mm}
 {% #1 = file name, #2 = list of names
  \clist_set:Nn \l__tisaigon_colornames_clist { #2 }
  \file_input:n { #1 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\colorlist}{m}
 {
  \int_zero:N \l__tisaigon_colornames_int
  \tl_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \int_incr:N \l__tisaigon_colornames_int
    \colorlet
     {
      \clist_item:Nn \l__tisaigon_colornames_clist { \l__tisaigon_colornames_int }
     }
     {
      ##1
     }
   }
 }
\clist_new:N \l__tisaigon_colornames_clist
\int_new:N \l__tisaigon_colornames_int
\ExplSyntaxOff

\assigncolors{\jobname.colors}{
  color1,
  color2,
  color3,
  header,
  body,
  footer,
  fancy,
}

\begin{document}

\textcolor{color1}{Abc}

\textcolor{color2}{Abc}

\textcolor{color3}{Abc}

\textcolor{header}{Abc}

\textcolor{body}{Abc}

\textcolor{footer}{Abc}

\textcolor{fancy}{Abc}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In a very simplistic way you can place a number of color definitions using (say) `\colorlet{colorX}{<colour>}` inside `color_array.tex` and load them within the document preamble:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% Just for this example, create control_array.tex that contains all the colour definitions
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{control_array.tex}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\colorlet{color1}{blue}
\colorlet{color2}{green}
\colorlet{color3}{red!30!yellow}
\colorlet{color4}{rgb:black,1;red,2;orange,3}
\colorlet{color5}{black!50}
\end{filecontents*}

\input{control_array}% Input colour definitions

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item \textcolor{color1}{Name1}
  \item \textcolor{color2}{Name2}
  \item \textcolor{color3}{Name3}
\end{enumerate}

\textcolor{color4}{Name9}

\textcolor{color5}{Name8}

\end{document}
```

Note that `\input{color_array}` is called within the preamble since `color_array.tex` includes a call to load [`xcolor`](//ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) which can only be called within the preamble.