# Create dynamic invisible character, dynamic spacing

Tags: spacing

i use array from topic: [Global variable Array](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474792/global-variable-array)

Now i want set dynamic spacing/blank for item in array.

Count space character of item and insert these space into pdf

Example: 3. rows (blue) in array with length= 10 space/10 invisible characters and 0.3 cm height.

Or how can i add ex: \hphantom \hspace in  \def\ArrayNames

Minimal coding:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\def\ArrayNames{{"koala", %1
"........", %2
"         ", %3 blue % need insert 10 invisible character / dynamic space - invisible text 
"penguin", %4
"bear" %5
}}
\def\ArrayColors{{"gray","yellow","blue","red","brown"}}
\begin{enumerate}
\foreach \X in {0,...,4}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myname}{\ArrayNames[\X]}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\mycolor}{\ArrayColors[\X]} 
\item \textcolor{\mycolor}{\myname} ABCDE
} 
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I am not an expert here and I do not fully get your question, so just some thoughts: **(1)** In a normal font (proportional fonts) every character has potentially a different width (opposite to typewriter font). So, maybe you mean a standard width, e. g. `1em` or `1ex`. **(2)** If yes, then maybe something like `\hspace*{10em}`?! **(3)** Alternatively, have a look at the `\hphantom{}` command (`\phantom{}` in general)´.

Comment: I am not sure how 10 invisible blue spaces are to look like but you could just use `"\hspace{5em}"` for that item (cf. @Dr.ManuelKuehner's comment).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Haha, I didn't get that the invisible spaces are supposed to be colored :).

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat and  Dr Manuel: thanks. how can i insert \hspace or \hphantom in item of def\ArrayNames

Comment: It is as simple as `\def\ArrayNames{{"koala", 
"........", 
"\hspace{5em}",
"penguin", 
"bear" 
}}`.

Comment: Thank. but when i use "\hspace{5em}", warning error in overleaf.com: Argument of \@mklab has an extra }.

<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.18 }

Comment: Maybe a `\protect{\hspace{5em}}` helps?!

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner SAME issue

Comment: Did you made a **step-by-step test** so that you know what part of the code works? Starting with `\begin{enumerate} \item \hspace*{5em} \end{enumerate}` (so no `\def` etc. at all) and then adding step-by-step more code.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner hi, i want to use hspace{5em} in \def\ArrayNames not in enumerate. Thanks

Comment: This was just an example. You know best how to break down your problem into smaller pieces. Then use `\textcolor{red}{\hspace*{3em}}` or `\textcolor{red}{\phantom{123}}` or something else to start with.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner thanks. My data not always same row/item, sometimes need spacing in other item/rows.

Comment: I am not sure, that you understand my suggestion, last trial: Break down your problem in smaller pieces and then focus on the core problem. The core problem is maybe easier to be asked here. Not everyone has the time/expertise to dig deep into the question of the OP.